# How can I register an articulated model to noisy predictions?

Tags: transformations, algorithm

[image: Sample scenario]

Given point sets $Y$ and $M$, I'd like to register articulated $M$ to $Y$ without changing the edge distances of $M$. The point correspondences between $Y$ and $M$ are known and points have a fixed connectivity map.

As you can see from the above sample, the edge distances of $Y$ are corrupted, and I'd like to correct them using $M$ while sacrificing some localization precision.

I know ICP and RANSAC algorithms, but none of them solve the articulation problem. I'm looking for any kind of algorithms that can solve this articulated body registration problem.